# Как сделать так чтобы калькулятор считал туда и обратно при умножении на коэфициент?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 <div class="d-none d-md-block">
        <div class="card__line mt-2 mt-xl-3 mb-2 mb-xl-3"></div>
        <div class="calc-inner-block">
            <input type="text" id="tons" value="1" oninput="calc()" />тн.
            <input type="text" id="result" value="1" oninput="calc()"> м.
            <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="text" id="coef" value="25" oninput="calc()" />
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function calc() {

                var tons = document.getElementById("tons");
                var coef = document.getElementById("coef");

                var result = document.getElementById("result");

                var sum = 0;

                sum = parseInt(tons.value) * parseInt(coef.value);

                result.innerHTML = sum;

            }

        </script>

    </div>
```

Comment: сделайте две функции для oninput - в одной умножайте, в другой делите

Comment: Спасибо большое!